# Serve a file in location directiv with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have various files in the directory '/var/www/something'.
The normal root of my nginx server is '/var/www/html'.

Now I want to serve only the file '/var/www/something/file.exp' as http://someserver.org/ecos/file.exp.

---

My current configuration uses something like that:

```
location =/ecos/file.exp {
   rewrite '^/ecos/(.*)$' '/$1' last;
   root /var/www/something;
}
```

, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tweak the rewrite to use `break`, not `last`:

```
location = /ecos/file.exp {
   rewrite '^/ecos/(.*)$' '/$1' last break;
   root /var/www/something;
}
```

From what I understand:

With `break`, the server will look for the file using the root at the current location:

```
location = /ecos/file.exp {
   ...
   root /var/www/something;
}
```

With `last`, the server will continue processing and use the rewritten location:

```
location = / {
   ...
   root /some/other/root;
}
```

See also: [nginx url rewriting: difference between break and last](https://serverfault.com/questions/131474/nginx-url-rewriting-difference-between-break-and-last)

Comment: Guess, it should be `alias var/www/something/file.exp;`

Comment: When I try the solution from the answer, I get a 403 forbidden message, when I request 'http://someserver.org/ecos/file.exp'.

Comment: I looked at the access permissions on my file system and changed them, such that they match the ones from '/var/www/html'. Since then I get a 404 not found message